# How to rename the Text OK and cancel of the org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm using the Message Dialog of org.eclipse.jface.dialogs and i need to rename the 'Ok' and 'Cancel' text in the buttons displayed. How to go about ?

Comment: Are these message dialogs you are displaying or ones that Eclipse is displaying?

Comment: yes. These are the default dialogs

Answer (score 2):

MessageDialog requestRestartDialog = new MessageDialog(window.getShell(), "Title", null,
                            "Message to be displayed", MessageDialog.CONFIRM, new String[] { "String 1", "String 2" }, 0);
                    int index = requestRestartDialog.open();

index will return the array index of the label specified.